# Only allow specific iOS devices to view website

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, ios, ipad

Is there any way to lock a web site to a specific iOS device?

For example, if I could use the UID so only users with a UID that i know can get to the site.

I could use username and password but I don't want my users to be able to share their account others.

I have thought of using cookies. Save a cookie when the user logs in for the first time and if he tries to log in on another device it wont work because I've programmed it to only save a cookie for each account.

But is there a better way?

Comment: That must be a very secret website you've got there, man.

Answer (score 4):

Developing a native application for iPhone is tbe  best possible solution for this issue. By this way, you can check the uuid and confirm that the authenticated user logs in from the same device. I do not find any alternative way to do this authentication at web end.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. Due to privacy-issues you cannot request the device UDID using Javascript (nor do you get it in a HTTP-header). You could try blocking all IPs except some, but that won't work that good, so you probably can't.

Comment: Mkay, just as I thought. Cookies seems to be the only solution then?

Comment: yeah cookies is your solution!

Comment: Well, I don't think that's a good solution either. By restarting your iDevice you'll destroy all your cookies, so you lose your access ... You could try to store a unique key in the app-storage (html5) which is an encrypted key of some variables (so you can't hijack them).

Comment: Ouch, they do :/ I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cookies is not a feasible solution for this issue. If the user clears the cookies or restart the device, he lose access to the site. Further, we cannot get UID using javascript. If you are in a stage where you could not move forward unless you get a solution, I can suggest you one.

You should thing of implementing a native application which authenticate the user and allow access to the web. By this, you can verify the UID to make sure that is accessed from a specific device.

Hope this helps.

Every problem has (n+1) solutions, where n is the number of solutions that you have tried and 1 is that you have not tried. :)

Answer (score 0):

post udid with a mobileconfig. like http://whatisyourudid.com